# How to make the navigation buttons to float on the Image in a slider

Tags: css

Hello I'm trying to make a slider using responsive slider form, I want the navigation Buttons to sit on the Image and not below the Image. Is there any trick or way to do it. Please help me. thanks

Second slide Transparent buttons over the left and right side
[Link](http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.html)

Comment: show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of your CSS file:

```
ul.centered-btns_tabs.centered-btns1_tabs {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but the Radio button is sitting behind the Slider Images i want it to be on top of the images

Comment: I tried it myself and it works for me. Please send a link to your site  so I can have a look.